# Chromecast Brain Freeze Error

Tags: chromecast, google-cast

I have registered and uploaded my receiver.html file (receiver app) and registered it hence I have got an app ID from Google. So when I tried to cast same app, It shows me error on TV is **Chrome Cast Brain Freeze**

I tried to debug through it, So I opened Chrome-Cast in debug mode and I captured the screenshot of error message [image: Debug Screenshot].

But when I enter URL of file `(given during registration of receiver app)`, it opens in my browser, means URL is not incorrect.

So what is the problem exactly, what is missing or am I doing something wrong??

I am strucked badly over here. cant able to proceed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you see the url that it shows on the very first line of your error in the debugger?

Comment: I guess you didn't get my point. Check your receiver to see why that url has "undefined" in it.

Comment: Still I am not clear what you are trying to say, sorry for that but as far as I understood, I have checked my Receiver app, It doesn't have any "undefined" in it. Also, When I followed that link from the same point, it is giving me 404 error.

Comment: Rohit, you need to develop some debugging skills and if I am not mistaking, this is not the first time I am suggesting this to you. If the error you are getting is coming from your receiver, figure out why it is trying to load that url; it is in your code somewhere.

Comment: After clicking on cast button, It should load receiver file instead It is showing me this error. That url is no where in my receiver app. I checked my code. Also in debug mode I have shared what I have got

Comment: What is the url for your receiver? What sender are you using?

Comment: android sender, url of receiver is: `https://hts.intellwiz.com/MyReceiver/receiver.html`

Comment: The certificate on the site you are hosting your receiver is not valid, you need to use valid certificates otherwise chromecast will not load your page.